# Faster way of calulating values in multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, performance

```
0 => array(
    'key1' = value
    'key2' = value
    }
1 => array(
    'key1' = value
    'key2' = value
    }
```

Is there a fast way of getting the sum of id=>key1 and id2=key1 so that I don't have to loop through?

I'd like it to see the array as

```
array(
    0 = value (key1)
    1 = value (key1)
)
```

But if it isn't built in somehow, it probably would be another step.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with huge arrays I doubt the impact of looping will be too big to manage. Don't worry about performance until you have a performance problem.  First and foremost of things your programs should be is correct.

Comment: It wouldn't be such a bad feature though, would it?  to quickly index multidimensional arrays by a contained key value if asked for.  It seems like something people would want to do.  Maybe my data model isn't great if it requires loops like this.

Comment: thanks GordonM.  :)  well said.  The arrays can be very big and some of the bigger ones are taking .08 seconds - and I might need to do 20 or more at a time for a web facing application.  I'd like to keep the render time at least under half a second but I don't think anyone will complain if it takes a second.

Comment: it would require a 'loop' even if it was an internal function, you seem to be seeking magic

Comment: Dagon, that is funny.  I thought that some internal functions were handled natively and therefore offer a difference in performance.

Comment: @justin Maybe caching the results would be a better option than trying to find a way to calculate it more rapidly.  Most data gets accessed far more often than it changes.

Comment: you can view the source of php, and see all its internal loops (array_map et al)

Comment: @GordonM Yeah that is another great point.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd consider this answered.  What I was looking for specifically isn't available.  Do I delete the question now or wait for someone to offer an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP 5.5's array_column() function

```
$result = array_sum(
    array_column(
        $myArray,
        'key1'
    )
);
```

for PHP < 5.5

```
$result = array_sum(
    array_map(
        $myArray,
        function ($value) { return $value['key1']; }
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I don't have php 5.5 and had read about array_map, but hadn't figured out how to use it.  All of the different options reduce/walk/etc had been a bit confusing.

Comment: and they still all uses loops :-)